# Python Programming- Defining a Class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

**This is the problem,**

Define the class Rectangle. It's constructor takes a pair of numbers representing the top-left corner, and two other numbers representing the width and height. It has the following methods:

`get_bottom_right()` - return the bottom right corner as a pair of numbers.
 `move(p)` - move the rectangle so that p becomes the top-left corner (leaving the width and height unchanged).
resize(width, height) - set the width and height of the rectangle to the supplied arguments (leaving the top-left corner unchanged).
 `__str__()` - return the string representation of the rectangle as a pair of pairs - i.e. the top left and bottom right corners.

Note: Unlike the co-ordinate system you may have encountered before, y, in this question, increases as you move vertically downwards.

Examples: 
Each example below follows on from the previous one. 
Be careful to get the spacing right for str - i.e. comma followed by space.

```
r = Rectangle((2,3), 5, 7)

str(r)

*'((2, 3), (7, 10))'*

r.move((5,6))

str(r)

'((5, 6), (10, 13))'

r.resize(2,3)

str(r)

*'((5,6), (7, 9))'*

r.get_bottom_right()

*(7, 9)*
```

**This is my answer:**

```
class Rectangle():

   def __init__(self, coords, sizex, sizey):
       self._startx, self._starty = coords
       self._sizex = sizex
       self._sizey = sizey
   def get_bottom_right(self):
       print '(%s, %s)' % (self._startx + self._sizex, self._starty + self._sizey)
   def move(self, pos):
       self._startx, self._starty = pos
   def resize(self, width, height):
       self._sizex = width
       self._sizey = height
   def __str__(self):
       return '((%s, %s), (%s, %s))' % (self._startx, self._starty, self._startx + self._sizex,   self._starty + self._sizey)

r = Rectangle((2, 3), 5, 7)

str(r)

r.move((5,6))

str(r)

r.resize(2,3)

str(r)

r.get_bottom_right()
```

I got the correct answer but the homeowork system says im wrong.

*Wrong: the Rectangle class should inherit from the object class*

can anyone tell me where im wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for,

```
class Rectangle(object):
...
```

This is a new-style class. Read more in this SO post: [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

I also have a feeling that your homework system is using `pylint` to verify/grade your code. You might want to stick to [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standards.

Comment: (object) is indeed the new style

Comment: I have changed to Rectangle(object), but why does my answer changes as well. It was (7,9) and it is (14,11) now. what is happening....

Comment: @bboychua Check if you've changed the numbers by mistake? There is no way inheriting object is affecting it.

Comment: okay this is what happened. if I use Rectangle(), I get (7,9), and if I use Rectangle(object), I get different answers everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Another error in your Rectangle class is that the `get_bottom_right()` method is supposed to *return* a tuple, **not** print it. Of course, returning a tuple in the interpreter without assigning it will cause it to be printed.